# how to show in between ids and only id when status is matched by using perl cgi and mysql?

Tags: html, mysql, perl, cgi

I just started using Perl CGI and MySQL database with html template. I have one table called "reserve" and template called Show.html.Now i am showing maximum reserve_id. But how can show in between ids and only id when reserve_status is 3.

1. Table data[reserve]:

```
reserve_id  reserve_status
34001             2
34002             2
34003             3
34004             3
35001             3
35002             3
35003             2
36000             3
36000             2
37000             3
37001             3
37002             2
40000             1
40001             3
40002             1
```

2. File[TextBookCommonStudent]:

```
sub GetReceiptNumber(){
    my $self = shift;
    my $status = shift;
    my $dbh = $self->{'dbh'};

    my $sql = "select *, MAX(reserve_id) as id from reserve where reserve_status = ? ";
    my @keys = ('reserve_status');
    return $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql, @keys, undef, $status);
}
```

3. File[index.cgi] :

```
use TextBookCommonStudent;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

my $TextBookCommonStudent = TextBookCommonStudent->_new()->DBConnect();

get '/Show' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my @breadcrumb = ('Show');

    my $ReceiptNumber = $TextBookCommonStudent->GetReceiptNumber('3');
    my $number = $ReceiptNumber->{'3'}->{'id'};
    $self->stash('ReceiptNumber'=> $number);

    $self->stash('breadcrumb'=> \@breadcrumb);
    $self->render('Show');
};
```

4. Template[Show.html] :

```
<%
    use Data::Dumper;
    my $ReceiptNumber = stash('ReceiptNumber');
%>
<div class="row">
    reserve numbers: <%= $ReceiptNumber %>
</div>
```

**Output** currently showing :

```
reserve numbers: 40001
```

but i want to show in following way :

```
reserve numbers: 34003~35002,36000,37001~37002,40001
```

How can i show data in above way by perl cgi.

Comment: You will have to give us a lot more details. You say you are using the CGI.pm module, but  you are using a function `get` that is not something CGI provides. Is that from some framework that you haven't shown us? What is your template engine?

Comment: CGI is not recommended for new projects. There are other alternatives that are better. Read [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

> I just started using Perl CGI

You have no idea how depressing it is to read that in 2022. Please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and reconsider.

Please let us know what Perl modules you are using. I don't recognise the `<%= $ReceiptNumber %>` syntax in your template. And what supplies the `get => '/Show' { ... }` syntax that you're using in your CGI code? It's not a standard CGI feature.

But, mostly, your problem seems to come down to needing to change your SQL. Your current SQL is this:

```
select *, MAX(reserve_id)
from   reserve
where  reserve_status = ?
```

This returns three columns, where the third column will always be the same value. It seems a rather strange way to query the data that you want - especially as in the code you ignore most of this data and just extract a single `receipt_id` from the data structure.

And I've just noticed that you're using `selectall_hashref()` and giving it `reserve_status` as the key column. So you're selecting one row for each reserve with a status of 3. But as DBI is processing the resultset, it overwrites the same value in the hash each time and you only end up with one key/value pair in your hash.

All in all, your code looks rather confused. And your question is hard to answer without knowing a lot more about what you're trying to do and the tools that you are trying to use.